# How to find the median and standard deviation by job in the below data in python?

Tags: python, csv

I have CSV file like below and i want to calculate the median and standard deviation of salaries by each job

salaries.csv

```
City   Job      Salary    
Delhi  Doctors  500  
Delhi  Lawyers  400  
Delhi  Plumbers 100  
London Doctors  800  
London Lawyers  700  
London Plumbers 300  
Tokyo  Doctors  900  
Tokyo  Lawyers  800  
Tokyo  Plumbers 400
```

From the above data i want to calculate the median and standard deviation of salaries by each job

Expected Output 1:

```
JOB      salary_median
Doctors  400
Lawyers  700
plumbers 300
```

Expected output 2:
    JOB      salary_std_dev
    Doctors  500
    Lawyers  600
    plumbers 400

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect task for pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
                   ['Delhi',  'Doctors',  500],
                   ['Delhi',  'Lawyers',  400],
                   ['Delhi',  'Plumbers', 100],
                   ['London', 'Doctors',  800],
                   ['London', 'Lawyers',  700],
                   ['London', 'Plumbers', 300],
                   ['Tokyo',  'Doctors',  900],
                   ['Tokyo',  'Lawyers',  800],
                   ['Tokyo',  'Plumbers', 400]],
                  columns = ['City',   'Job',      'Salary'])

print df.groupby('Job').Salary.median().to_frame('salary_median')
```